# "non-Bousfield" localisations of model categories 

Tags: model-categories

When can I localise a model category by a set(or class) of morphisms, 
and how do I describe the localised model category ?

By 'localise' I mean to find a localisation functor $q_S : M \rightarrow M_S$ 
with the usual universality property: that is, $q_S(s)$ is a weak equivalence for any $s\in S$, and any functor $q:M \rightarrow M'$ with this property factors through $q_S$. Importantly, $M_S$ and $M$ may have *different* underlying categories and so it is not necessarily a Bousfield localisation.

The model category ([defined here)](http://corrigenda.ru/by:gavrilovich-and-hasson/what:a-homotopy-theory-for-set-theory/Exercises_de_style_A_homotopy_theory_for_set_theory-I.pdf) I am interested in, is very degenerate: its underlying category is a partially ordered set (or class).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's essentially a sort of set-theoretic condition on the class of morphisms we want to localize at? That is, we basically take (homotopy) colimits over acyclics w.r.t. to our class W of morphisms, and if that class is generated under homotopy colimits by a set, then our localization exists.

Comment: I believe your universal property will force the underlying categories to be equal. I mean, you could take $M'$ to be the model structure on $M$ where the weak equivalences are the isomorphisms and all maps are both fibrations and cofibrations.

Comment: If my comment above is correct, then the Bousfield localization (if it exists) will be the localization in your sense, by its well-known universal property. However, your type should always exist (because the class of $M'$ is nonempty, so you can just take the one "closest" to $M$) even if Bousfield localization does not. But because you haven't required the cofibrations in $M$ and $M_S$ to match up, I'm not sure if yours is good for anything. Still, +1 since it got me thinking.

Comment: Quite the opposite, I want cofibrations to change. The point is, there is a sequence of related model category structures (with more and more cofibrations), and I wanted to see whether it is a sequence of localisations

Comment: thanks for your responses. I just saw them now, (and do not get email notifications), and not sure if you'll ever see my response...